# What language is this Program in?

Tags: windows

This is a program to hide/lock and unhide/unlock a folder.

I got it from http://ccm.net/faq/8073-lock-folder-with-password

Which language is it ?

It is to be saved as a .bat file and to run it,we should open that .bat file.

(Instructions are given in the link)

> cls
>
> @echo off
>
> title Folder Locker
>
> IF EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B303--09D}" GOTO
> UNLOCK
>
> IF NOT EXIST Locker GOTO MDLOCKER
>
> echo Folder Created.
>
> :CONFIRM
>
> echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder? (Y/N)
>
> set/p "cho="
>
> IF %cho%==Y GOTO LOCK
>
> IF %cho%==y GOTO LOCK
>
> IF %cho%==N GOTO END
>
> IF %cho%==n GOTO END
>
> echo Invalid Choice.
>
> GOTO CONFIRM
>
> :LOCK
>
> ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B303--09D}"
>
> attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B303--09D}"
>
> echo Folder Locked.
>
> GOTO END
>
> :UNLOCK
>
> echo Enter password :
>
> set/p "pass="
>
> IF NOT %pass% == YourPassWord GOTO FAIL
>
> attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B303--09D}"
>
> ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B303--09D}" Locker
>
> echo Folder Unlocked Successfully.
>
> GOTO END
>
> :FAIL
>
> echo Invalid Password!
>
> GOTO END
>
> :MDLOCKER
>
> md Locker
>
> echo Folder created.
>
> GOTO END
>
> :END
>
> PAUSE?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows Batch script

Answer (score 0):

It's a list of batch commands that forms a batch-file. Not actually a program but a script.

Answer (score 0):

Hi follow the link for detail about this [language](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting). This language is called  [MSDOS shell commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).